# How to "record" and "replay" touch events in android?

Tags: java, android, events, touch

I'm trying to code an app that interacts with other apps, screen touches, etc'.

To get things started - all I want is a button, that once clicked it starts saving information about actions taken: screen touches, keyboard strokes, etc'. Once clicked again it stops. After this another button, once clicked, repeats the exact same actions.

How to interact in such a way? I can't find information about the code words needed, how it works, etc'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're looking for a [command pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern)

for each click you create a command and put it onto a stack and execute it. later you can 'replay' all commands if you iterate through these commands

Comment: Okay - I got the theory, but how do I find documentation for the syntax?

For example - if I import android.view.MotionEvent I can use event.getX or event.getY to get the coordinates of a touch, but I can't find any more information..

Comment: you can call the Methods from the listener, e.g. call `onTouch()` with the MotionEvent stored in your command.

Answer (score 3):

Try the appetizer-toolkit: https://github.com/appetizerio/appetizer-toolkit

It records touchscreen events and replay back to devices with same aspect ratios.